# Connection reset after php include

Tags: php, apache, include, wamp

I've been working with php-ews for a project i'm working on.

upon including the repository via a scandir loop and a few manual entries

```
include ("php-ews/ExchangeWebServices.php");
include ("php-ews/EWS_Exception.php");
include ("php-ews/EWSType.php");
include ("php-ews/NTLMSoapClient.php");
include ("php-ews/NTLMStream.php");
include ("php-ews/NTLMStream/Exchange.php");

$dir    = '/wamp/www/intranet/dashboard/php-ews/EWSType/';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files1 as $value) {
if(preg_match('/\.php$/i', $value)){
$inc = "php-ews/EWSType/";
$inc .= $value;
include ($inc);
}}
```

i then proceed to add one of the next includes

```
include ("php-ews/NTLMSoapClient/Exchange.php");
```

and the page is no longer loadable in any browser giving connection reset errors in firefox, however this is instant and not a timeout issue. upon commenting that line out it goes back to asking for it to be included.

contents of the file below

```
class NTLMSoapClient_Exchange extends NTLMSoapClient {
    /**
     * Username for authentication on the exchnage server
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * password for authentication on the exchnage server
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param string $wsdl
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
        // verify that a user name and password were entered
        if (empty($options['user']) || empty($options['password'])) {
            throw new EWS_Exception('A username and password is required.');
        } // end if no user name and password were entered

        // set the username and password properties
        $this->user = $options['user'];
        $this->password = $options['password'];

        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    } // end function __construct()
} // end class NTLMSoapClient_Exchange
```

the code repository is at http://code.google.com/p/php-ews/source/browse/ if you need anymore reference.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Xdebug running? Sounds more like it's taking over, I'd look at the dll. This is common with XAMPP - possibly an uncaught exception on that constructor spitting a fatal error.

Comment: @alienwebguy I do not have xdebug running, normally just querying DB's so have never needed it. I'm pretty sure the included files won't be causing the issue as there a confirmed working version of a googlecode project.

Comment: You may need to check your apache log files. Usually connection resets mean PHP or Apache actually derped. If you find something there, that may help shine some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

It Happens in-case when you have included the class already and we try to include that file again.
To prevent this use include_once & also check use code whether that class is included again (before or after).